# How to make a route in google map with url and parameters between origin and destination?

Tags: ios, google-maps, routes, direction, google-maps-urls

I want to open a **url** in web and automatically make a route between two points. I can't find correct url and params in **google map** document.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this in **Swift 4** :

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://maps.google.com")
        if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!))
        {
            let originLat:String = String(locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
            let originLong:String = String(locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
            let destLat:String = String(locationObj.latitude)
            let destLong:String = String(locationObj.longitude)

            let openUrlString:String = String(format:"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=%@,%@&destination=%@,%@&travelmode=driving",originLat,originLong,destLat,destLong)

            print("openUrlString is : \(openUrlString)")


            let openUrl = URL(string: openUrlString)
            UIApplication.shared.open(openUrl!, options: [:]) { (res:Bool) in

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

And for **Swift 4** and **swift 5**

```
let apiKey = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/" + userCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude + "," + userCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude + "/" + nextCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude + "," + nextCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                
    var url = URL(string: apikey)
```

For objective c use

```
   NSString *apikey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/%f,%f/%f,%f",userCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude,userCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude,nextCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude,nextCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:apikey];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```